# SQL query: How to identify group differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | subgroup1 | 54 |
| group1 | subgroup1 | 31 |
| group1 | subgroup2 | 54 |
| group1 | subgroup2 | 55 |
| group2 | subgroup3 | 40 |
| group2 | subgroup3 | 41 |
| group2 | subgroup4 | 40 |
| group2 | subgroup4 | 41 |

Each group has a number of subgroups and each subgroup has a number of values.

I need to filter out the group that has the same value in col3. For example, group2 has values(40,41)

only return group1 as subgroup1(54,31) and subgroup2(54,55) shares different values(31, 55) in col3. How can I achieve this in SQL?

Desire result:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | subgroup1 | 54 |
| group1 | subgroup1 | 31 |
| group1 | subgroup2 | 54 |
| group1 | subgroup2 | 55 |

Comment: Please your desired results as a dataset in addition to explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You could use string_agg(). ie:

```
select col1, col2, string_agg(col3, ',')
from mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  col1 VARCHAR(10),
  col2 VARCHAR(10),
  col3 varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO mytable
  (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
  ('group1', 'subgroup1', '54'),
  ('group1', 'subgroup1', '31'),
  ('group1', 'subgroup2', '54'),
  ('group1', 'subgroup2', '55'),
  ('group2', 'subgroup3', '40'),
  ('group2', 'subgroup3', '41'),
  ('group2', 'subgroup4', '40'),
  ('group2', 'subgroup4', '41');

select col1, col2, string_agg(col3, ',')
from mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

| col1 | col2 | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | subgroup1 | 54,31 |
| group1 | subgroup2 | 54,55 |
| group2 | subgroup3 | 40,41 |
| group2 | subgroup4 | 40,41 |

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cWqLLAxR)

EDIT: According to your edited and changed requirement:

```
with dummy as
(select col1, col2, string_agg(col3, ',') col3
from mytable
group by col1, col2
),
  unq as 
  (
select col3
from dummy
group by col3
having count(*) = 1
)
select * from dummy 
where exists (select col3 from unq where dummy.col3 = unq.col3);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/05OTdS2w)

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: @Saddy, yes sadly you did it too late after I wasted my time :( And I am afraid it is not understandable now.

Comment: Thanks Cetin, I think your answer is what I am looking for. One more thing, is it possible to re-order the number? e.g. 31,54

Comment: @Saddy, I don't know need to think about it. If it were postgreSQL instead of SQL server, I would say yes right away. SQL server isn't as capable as that to make it easy.